# Handling authentication for multiple apps under the same account - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, authentication

Working for a company where we are starting to have many small apps, each with their own log in screen.

So that means whenever someone's password changes, they'll have to re enter their password for every app

Can be cumbersome to the user, especially when our policy is to have user's passwords change every 3 months and there are 6 or more apps to enter the password on

Has anyone come up with a work around for this problem where the user would only have to enter their password once? I'm thinking I could have one dedicated app solely for authenticating and then do some kind of interprocess communication if that's even possible

Again, doing this for iOS. I know on Android it wouldn't be an issue because developers can add accounts in the settings screen. However, iOS is a different beast

*Note these are enterprise, in house only apps. Not public facing on the app store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the username/pwd on keychain and share them between apps as mentioned [here](http://shaune.com.au/ios-keychain-sharing-data-between-apps/)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/sharing_access_to_keychain_items_among_a_collection_of_apps

Comment: I wish you could post the answer in the stackoverflow answer area in case the link ever gets deleted

Comment: @MobileMon well if that ever happens we can always post the answer, but I think it's only fair to credit the original author by linking here.

Comment: Aaannndd it was deleted...haha